# How can I add double quote between double quotes to be a string value?

Tags: ios, swift, string, filter

I want to filter double quotes in my text and separate from the words. But When I added the double quote in double quotes (like this """ ), it didn't work. I tried to add with this way ("\"") in between double quotes but it didn't work too.

My codes are as below. You can see in FindCommonWords function what I want.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import ROGoogleTranslate
import SwiftSoup

class FeedDetailVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var txtMain: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblHeader: UILabel!

var commonWordsArray = [String]()
var selectedHeader = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    lblHeader.text = selectedHeader
    self.txtMain.sizeToFit()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.contentHeight = self.lblHeader.frame.height + self.txtMain.frame.height
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.contentHeight + 100)
        self.reloadInputViews()

    }

    findCommonWords()

}


func findCommonWords() {

    let textViewText = txtMain.text


    var commonWords = textViewText?.lowercased().components(separatedBy: [" ",".",",","=","(",")","-","/",":","\""]).filter({ !$0.isEmpty })

    let rejectedWords: [String] = ["the","on","in","a","an","of","off","up","and","to","are","is","am","—","se","iphone","was","it","at","\""]


    for index in rejectedWords {
    commonWords = commonWords?.filter{ $0 != index}

    }


    let wordCounts = NSCountedSet(array: commonWords!)


    let sortedWords = wordCounts.allObjects.sorted(by: {wordCounts.count(for: $0) > wordCounts.count(for: $1) }) [0..<5]

    yPoint = self.txtMain.frame.height + 15

    for word in sortedWords {

    //print("\(word) \(wordCounts.count(for: word)) times")

    let sortedWordsLabel = UILabel()
    sortedWordsLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 25)
    sortedWordsLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 80, y: yPoint)
    sortedWordsLabel.text = word as? String
    sortedWordsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15)
    sortedWordsLabel.textAlignment = .left

    self.scrollView.addSubview(sortedWordsLabel)
    yPoint += 25

    commonWordsArray.append(word as! String)

    }

}

}
```

Comment: When you say `"\""` "Does not work", what does it actually do and what do you want to happen?

Comment: Also, you should shrink your code down to the [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can better help you fix your issue without digging through unrelated code

Comment: I can't help you with an answer because I don't see what your issue is concerning but I do have some suggestions to simplify your code. I have a chat room open if you want to see them: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154187/swift-code-review

Comment: Actually, I want to filter " character from my text. If the text includes double quotes character, it should delete from commonWords. I wrote this in my question("I want to filter double quotes in my text and separate from the words.")Besides the codes aren't complex. Every programmer can understand easily. Anyway, it is not very important. If you don't want, you may not help.

Answer (score 0):

> “String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> The escaped special characters `\0` (null character), `\\` (backslash), `\t` (horizontal tab), `\n` (line feed), `\r` (carriage return), `\"` (double quote) and `\'` (single quote)”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1).” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/ca/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: This answer doesn't help since the code in the question is already properly escaping the `"` character in the string. Clearly the question is just about how to properly escape the quote character.

Comment: I meant "...the question *isn't* just about...".